# In an answer, is there a general prohibition on refuting arguments made in other answers?

Tags: discussion, behavior

Very often on programming issues, many answers are not only factually wrong, they also make detailed argument which are unfounded, logically incorrect, have subtle faults, etc. Yet these answers are very appealing and often have many upvotes and are accepted. (Many programming related questions don't have testable answers. Saying that program is correct is not testable in most languages, which allow non-determinism.)

So **I naturally want to address the incorrect claims made in other answers in mine, to refute them**. Is that allowed?

It may seem silly, but I have been told it was a violation of the "rules".

Comment: I would usually lay out the "correct" (or at least better) way to solve the problem and then spend a small part of the answer to detail why this is preferable to another approach. So, it goes something like "You can take approach A <details>. The difference with approach B shown here <link> is X, Y, and Z". Although a lot of times I don't think you need that many details. You can simply go "Here is how you can solve it <details>. This has advantages X, Y, and Z" without specifying compared to what. When I think an answer can stand on its own I try to avoid the comparison to another.

Comment: Who told you it's a violation of the rules?

Comment: In my [highest upvotes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes/7317311#7317311) I explain what the flaws are with the other answers' approaches. Nobody seems to care. What I did do at one point is remove the user names, because that's just unfriendly.

Comment: @CodeCaster It was a long time ago and I don't even have the link.

Answer (score 16):

Yes; you can absolutely point out faults or flaws in answers.  However, there's a constructive way to go about doing this.

If the premise of the answer is wrong and is otherwise untenable, it's better to reply with a *correct* answer highlighting the actual facts.  **This does not require any comments on any *other* answer**, as your only objective is to right a wrong.

If the premise of the answer is *mostly* wrong but can be saved, then a gentle comment on the answerer's post is acceptable, but it's always good to follow up with your own correct answer *too*.  To avoid making this into a "you're wrong, I'm right"-style debate, you would want to maybe comment once or twice, highlighting what you think they got wrong, and offer some cited resources reinforcing that position.

Comment: Yes I was not suggesting that posting "all existing answers are wrong" is sufficient to constitute a proper answer, but I want to be able to tell ppl to distrust other appealing but incorrect answers before presenting the correct answer (correct according to my own understand, it goes w/o saying).

Comment: At the end of the day...it's really up to the individual reader to determine if something is right or wrong.  All you can do is arm them with enough information and sources to help them make a better choice.